# How can I count the number of all votes per voter?

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is my **table structure**:

```
// users
+----+--------+
| id |  name  |
+----+--------+
| 1  | Jack   |
| 2  | Peter  |
| 3  | John   |
| 4  | Barman |
| 5  | Ali    |
+----+--------+

// vote
+----------+---------------+---------+
| voter_id | owner_post_id | post_id |
+----------+---------------+---------+
| 2        | 3             | 1653    |
| 4        | 2             | 1214    |
| 1        | 1             | 4355    |
| 4        | 2             | 6445    |
| 2        | 2             | 5465    |
| 3        | 2             | 5435    |
+----------+---------------+---------+
```

And here is my **current query**:

```
SELECT t2.id AS user_id,
       t2.name AS user_name,
       t3.id AS voter_id,
       t3.name AS voter_name
FROM vote t1
INNER JOIN users t2
    ON t1.owner_post_id = t2.id
INNER JOIN users t3
    ON t1.voter_id = t3.id
WHERE t1.owner_post_id = 2 AND
      t1.voter_id <> t1.owner_post_id
```

And here is my **current output**:

```
+---------+-----------+----------+------------+
| user_id | user_name | voter_id | voter_name |
+---------+-----------+----------+------------+
| 2       | Peter     | 4        | Barman     |
| 2       | Peter     | 4        | Barman     |
| 2       | Peter     | 3        | John       |
+---------+-----------+----------+------------+
```

---

Now I want to add one more column to the result which contains the total number of votes per voter. So this is **expected result**:

```
+---------+-----------+----------+------------+-----------+
| user_id | user_name | voter_id | voter_name | total_num |
+---------+-----------+----------+------------+-----------+
| 2       | Peter     | 4        | Barman     | 2         |
| 2       | Peter     | 3        | John       | 1         |
+---------+-----------+----------+------------+-----------+
```

How can I do that?

Comment: How to count => `COUNT(?) as x`

Comment: @Fred-ii- I know I have to both use `count(col)` and `group by` clause. But I don't know how should I use them in my current query.

Comment: Are you sure you only get Peter/Barman only once with your query? I think you must get the pair twice, because there are two vote records for the pair.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner You are right .. can you please tell me how can I remove duplicate rows ?

Comment: So you get the result row twice, because the pair twice in the vote table. And this is why you want total_num = 2 for the pair. Everything fine, and the answer you accepted should work for you, only that the result table you are showing for your own query is wrong.

Comment: I've corrected your query output now. (You could have done the same by simply pressing the edit button and performing a quick copy & paste.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get all votes for the user, aggregate them and count. Then join the user table twice; once for the user, once for the voter.

```
select
  usr.id as user_id, 
  usr.name as user_name, 
  vtr.id as voter_id, 
  vtr.name as voter_name,
  v.cnt as total_num
from 
(
  select owner_post_id, voter_id, count(*) as cnt
  from vote
  where owner_post_id = 2 and owner_post_id <> voter_id
  group by owner_post_id, voter_id
) v
join user usr on usr.id = v.owner_post_id
join user vtr on usr.id = v.voter_id;
```

And here is the same method applied to your real query. Just some other table and column names, so I think you should have been able to do this yourself.

```
select 
  pr1.id as user_id,
  pr1.title as user_name,
  pr2.id as liker_id,
  pr2.title as liker_name,
  x.which as which_table,
  x.cnt as total
from 
(
  select rid, rootid, which, count(*) as cnt
  from
  (
    select rid, rootid, 'vote' which from p_likes
    union all 
    select rid, rootid, 'comment' which from p_comments
    union all 
    select rid, rootid, 'friend' which from relations
  ) all_in_one
  where rootid = 1 and rootid <> rid
  group by rid, rootid, which
) x
join pagesroot pr1 on x.rootid = pr1.id
join pagesroot pr2 on x.rid = pr2.id
order by x.which;
```

Comment: Great query ..! upvote. Just can you please apply your idea on my [real query](https://gist.github.com/sajadshafizadeh/f968de5d1cbfd9500820047f19f0d8c4)?

Comment: *"I think you should have been able to do this yourself."*. should I do what thing exactly?! All  names you've used in your query seem right to me ...

Comment: I meant that it is not too hard to get from the user/vote query to the real query. The table names are different and so are some column names and you have the union-all subquery instead of a table. The only real difference is that you want different result rows per "which", so you must group by "which", too. Something you could have done by yourself instead of asking me, and you would have practised your SQL skills in the process.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t2.id AS user_id,
       t2.name AS user_name,
       t3.id AS voter_id,
       t3.name AS voter_name
       Count(t1.voter_id) AS total_num
FROM vote t1
INNER JOIN users t2
    ON t1.owner_post_id = t2.id
INNER JOIN users t3
    ON t1.voter_id = t3.id
WHERE t1.owner_post_id = 2 AND
      t1.voter_id <> t1.owner_post_id
GROUP BY t2.id AS user_id,
       t2.name,
       t3.id,
       t3.name
```

**EDIT:**

```
SELECT pr1.id AS user_id,
       pr1.title AS user_name,
       pr2.id AS liker_id,
       pr2.title AS liker_name,
       x.which AS which_table,
       COUNT(pr1.id) AS total
FROM (
SELECT rid, rootid, 'vote' which FROM p_likes
UNION ALL 
SELECT rid, rootid, 'comment' which FROM p_comments
UNION ALL 
SELECT rid, rootid, 'friend' which FROM relations
) x
INNER JOIN pagesroot pr1
      ON x.rootid = pr1.id
INNER JOIN pagesroot pr2
      ON x.rid = pr2.id
WHERE x.rootid = 1
      AND x.rootid <> x.rid
GROUP BY pr1.id,
       pr1.title,
       pr2.id,
       pr2.title,
       x.which
ORDER BY x.which
```

Comment: Thank you .. upvote .. but honestly my real query looks like [this](https://gist.github.com/sajadshafizadeh/f968de5d1cbfd9500820047f19f0d8c4). Can you please tell me how can I do that on my real query?